# Mutt: ask before deleting messages from Trash

Tags: mutt, trash, macro

I have defined in Mutt two "trash" macros -- one for the Trash folder (just mark as deleted and sync) and one for the remaining folders (save into Trash and sync):

```
folder-hook . 'macro index <delete> "s=Trash<enter><enter><sync-mailbox><change-folder>^<enter>"'
folder-hook =Trash 'macro index <delete> "<delete-message><sync-mailbox><change-folder>^<enter>"'
```

Together with `set delete = yes` this results in messages immediately being expunged, no questions asked. Such a behaviour is fine outside the Trash folder, however, I'd like Mutt to ask for confirmation before messages are deleted from Trash.

The only workaround that I have come up with so far is not to sync in the macro (i.e., use only `<delete-message>` there), thus having to live with deleted messages being present until I sync manually. (Which is not ideal...)

Is it possible to change this setup so that -- in Trash -- Mutt would ask for confirmation before actually marking the messages as deleted and expunging them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think changing *delete* option at the beginning of the macro to `ask-no` and reseting to `yes` at the end should do the trick.

```
folder-hook =Trash 'macro index <delete> "set delete=ask-no;<delete-message><sync-mailbox><change-folder>^<enter>set delete=yes"'
```

Comment: Thank you. Although since the time of posting the question I moved on to using `purge-message` without `sync-mailbox` (makes for a faster user experience with the option to undelete messages if need be), other people might still find your answer useful.